# Setup Spring and Spring-Security to use HTML file

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In a web application, we don't want to use JSP files, we want to use only HTML files. Each view is a template.

I'm looking for a way to setup spring, spring security to use directly login.html file and  if the user authentificates correctly the generic layout (top level, left level, right level and center level and south level) will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `natural templating` solution where the templates are built directly in HTML and CSS with just some special atributes in the tags, but without the need for a set of XML tag libraries.

One solution that allows this is the Thymeleaf templating technology - [Comparison of a Thymeleaf template with a JSP in a Spring application](http://www.thymeleaf.org/thvsjsp.html)

this is how a template looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Spring MVC view layer: Thymeleaf vs. JSP</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
          href="../../css/thvsjsp.css" th:href="@{/css/thvsjsp.css}"/>
</head>

<body>

<h2>This is a Thymeleaf template</h2>

<form action="#" th:object="${subscription}" th:action="@{/subscribeth}">

    <fieldset>

        <div>
            <label for="email" th:text="#{subscription.email}">Email: </label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label th:text="#{subscription.type}">Type: </label>
            <ul>
                <li th:each="type : ${allTypes}">
                    <input type="radio" th:field="*{subscriptionType}" th:value="${type}" />
                    <label th:for="${#ids.prev('subscriptionType')}"
                           th:text="#{'subscriptionType.'+${type}}">First type</label>
                </li>
                <li th:remove="all"><input type="radio" /> <label>Second Type</label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="submit">
            <button type="submit" name="save" th:text="#{subscription.submit}">Subscribe me!</button>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would like to know if we can do theses thing with Thymeleaf: 

I would like to split the web site like that:  
 
  north part  
  south part  
  east part  
  west part  
  center part  

  So probably all this part could be in layout.html 

  when i arrive on the web site, i would like to inject the content of login.html in the center part. 

  So if it's possible, how to said my first web page is layout.html, how to do the injection?

Comment: have a look at this example with header and footer http://www.thymeleaf.org/petclinic.html